# Use Higher api level featurers in the lower api level devices

Tags: android

I have developed my application by using sdk version 10.In lower version doesn't have the features which is available in the higher version's.Is there any api is available to use the higher level api features in the lower api level devices.

Note:
For example we unable to get the camera count in the api level 8, but we can get the details in the api level 9.If we try to use that feature application shows the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible you need to implment that, or use some compatibility pack to get the functionallity.

But note that not everything is possible to emulate. E.g. the Base64 classes to implement is easy, but it is impossible to add the NFC functionallity to older releases because the needed hardware is missing.

You can simply check the actual android version and build a switch so you won't call any functions that are not aviable to that device. That is possible with the constant [android.os.Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).